# Unknown attribute @Validation.For("orderName")

Tags: javascript, html, forms, webmatrix

I am trying to pull the Order Form out of the Bakery Template to use in my web page.  When pulling the section of HTML, I am getting the following error in the code: Unknown attribute @Validation.For("orderName")

```
                <div class="fieldcontainer" data-role="fieldcontain">
                   <label for="orderPhone">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="orderName" name="orderName" @Validation.For("orderName")/>                
                <div>@Html.ValidationMessage("orderName")</div>
                </div>
```

I am assuming it is because I don't have the right .js file loaded.  Does anyone know, or can anyone tell me which specific .js file I need to also pull from the Bakery template and load in my page Head?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the HTML output for that snippet?

Comment: I just added a piece of the form.  The just of it is that it prompts the user to enter their Name, if the Name field is blank it does some validation to prompt for it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code it's a little hard to tell what the problem is.

Regardless read this great article on Validation and Razor WebPages: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/191/Validation-In-Razor-Web-Pages-2